# Is Custom Text supported in Computed columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, calculated-columns

Is there any way of adding custom text in an computed column?

For example this formula works great `([Duration] + '12')`

Could i have a result, from a computed column, similar to this one?

`([Duration] & ' MyCustomText')`

Can i add custom text in a computed column? Or am i asking too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as you stick with correct T-SQl expresions:

```
(cast([Duration] as varchar(...)) + 'MyCustomText')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, when you define a computed column,  you can write any expression that the server can evaluate using the values in that table .. You just can't use column values from other tables...

Answer (score 0):

=[Column Name]&"My Custom Text"

Verified on Sharepoint 2010

for Column Type = Calculated (calculation based on other columns)

Answer (score 0):

SPACE ( integer_expression )

Example:
[column1] + SPACE(2) + [column2]